# scanf e getchar()

Tags: c, char, armazenamento

por que no segundo printf eu consigo usar apenas op=getchar(); mas no final preciso usar um scanf pra realizar a pergunta?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i, tab=0;
    char op,  n;
    do {
    printf("\ndigite um numero para ver a tabuada: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();//se livra do ENTER
    printf("\noperacao '*' para multiplicar,  '+' para somar: ");
    op = getchar();
        if(op == '*'){
        for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
            printf("\n%d", n*i);}}
        else if(op == '+'){
            for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
                printf("\n%d", n+i);
            }
        }

    printf("\nquer continuar? [S/N]");
    scanf("%c", &op);
    op= getchar();
    op=tolower(op);
    }while(op != 'n');
    }
```

Comment: Você utilizou uma maneira (talvez não das melhores) para limpar o buffer de entrada após scanf("%d", &n); mas não fez o mesmo após scanf("%c", &op);. Aliás da menira como fez estará atribuindo a op o caractere '\n' sobrescrevendo o que foi digitado (a menos que seja digitado mais de umS ou N).

Comment: Uma maneira de consumir este '\n' é colocar no formato de seus scanf um espaço: scanf(" %d", &n); e scanf(" %c", &op); e aí não precisará deste getchar para consumir o lixo do buffer de entrada. Utilize inclusive para ler op.

Comment: colocando um espaço antes do formato %c o \n (enter) é consumido, como foi sugerido pelo @anonimo; no formato %d isso não é necessário, os espaços e \n e \t ***antes*** dos dígitos do número são consumidos automaticamente